# How to keep braces on single line

Tags: javascript, netbeans, formatting

When I write JavaScript in NetBeans, I don't want my braces to go on newlines. I want my code to look like this:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify({prop1: v1, prop2: v2});
```

Not, this:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify({
    prop1: v1
    prop2: v2
});
```

But when I use the NetBeans "reformat" feature (ctrl+shift+F) it places my braces on new lines. This has been killing me for weeks now.

I found one solution on Google (`Tools->Options->Editor->Language->Braces`) but my version of NetBeans (7.2.1) on OS X doesn't have the `Tools->Options` menu item. Instead I've been hunting in `NetBeans->Preferences`, but to no avail.

Comment: are you sure you're using the same version of netbeans across both platforms?

Comment: I found the `Tools->Options` solution on google, but my version of NetBeans on OS X doesn't have `Tools->Options`. Instead, I use `NetBeans->Preferences`, but this doesn't seem to have a category for "braces".

Comment: Switch to the 2nd version to cure your hernia - it is more readable in the long run. Personally, I prefer to write already-formatted code on netbeans instead of depending on these auto-format tools.